# Conditional Display of Links in Widgets

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, widgets, customization, links

I want the links widget in my sidebar to display links based on the page the user is on. For example, if the user is on the home page I want it to display link1, link2 and link3. But if the user goes to the 'About' page I want the links widget to display link4 and link5.

Is there a way to specify conditional display of links depending on the page id?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widget Logic
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Also Query Posts Widget is very useful
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/15/query-posts-widget-wordpress-plugin

Comment: the query_posts widget is awesome

Comment: +1 for Widget Logic. It's not excessively flashy in interface, but makes possible very flexible and powerful widget configurations.