# How to have dynamic sidebar content per post

Tags: sidebar, templates

I am setting up a site for a client and have included a dynamic sidebar in the template for certain types of posts. I would like the client to be able to add a text widget to that sidebar for a post and put in content related to that post only. Is this possible in WordPress or is the text widget put in one post going to show up on all others?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/conditional-display-of-links-in-widgets/4540#4540

Comment: Thanks for the comment, while this seems like it will accomplish the functionality of what I am looking for it will not work from a client experience standpoint as it is a bit beyond their technical level.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Sidebar Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-generator/) it lets you specify a sidebar on a per-page/per-post basis.

some of its main features are:

- Generate unlimited sidebars
- pick a sidebar on a per-page and per-post basis
- unique CSS classes for each sidebar for customizable looks